# App Theme(Actionbar) is not respecting your space

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'm using a *Navigation Drawer*, but every time I put something in the fragment, the action bar does not respect the layout.

The image itself explains:

[image]

The fragment_main :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.leonel.picollo.MainFragment">

<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="MAIN"
   android:padding="8dp"
   android:textColor="#fff"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   android:textSize="28sp"
   android:id="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the MainFragment.java :

```
package com.example.leonel.picollo;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any (XML) code you can show us?

Comment: Of course, but which class?

Comment: Tasso Guimareas fragment_main.xml and MainFragment.class might also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using custom toolbar has some consequences. Custom toolbar has height and other elements don't respect it in default, we must set them padding or margin. Add to RelativeLayout marginTop on height of Toolbar.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" <!-- here is marginTop -->
tools:context="com.example.leonel.picollo.MainFragment">
</RelativeLayout>
```